# Field value not saving

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have module created with UMC ( ultimate module creator ) named consultancy. I have successfully added a field on Add/edit page with following code which I found in form.php file.

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'price_usd',
            'text',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('abhi_consulting')->__('Price USD'),
                'name'  => 'price_usd',
            'required'  => true,
            'class' => 'required-entry',

           )
        );
```

other fields were added same way so i just copy pasted and changed the key, now the field is available but the value is not saving and showing blank.

I looked into the code but didnt find any save function. How do I save value for new added field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save value you need to have filed in database too.

When you say

> so i just copy pasted and changed the key, now the field is available
>   but the value is not saving and showing blank

I believe you didn't create a column for this in your database.

You need to add an update sql then it will save as required.

Create a file- `sql/your_setup_name/upgrade-[your-current-version]-[any-version].php`

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('abhi_consulting/yourmodel'),
        'price_usd',
        array(
            'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
            'precision' => 12,
            'scale'     => 4,
            'nullable'  => true,
            'default'   => null,
            'comment'   => 'Your comment'
        )
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

**You need to change `yourmodel` to your own model, not sure how you have setup your config.xml.**

Now,

Simply go to your `etc/config.xml` and update your version. Basically it should match with `[any-version]` exactly.

Hope this is clear for you.

Comment: thanks @Adarsh , I did what you suggest but now getting following error as I am new to magento, not sure how to resolve this.  Call to undefined method Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::run()

Comment: Can you add your config.xml and also folder structure screenshot please.

Comment: I ended up by adding the field directly through phpmyadmin, will look into it after finishing the task.

Comment: I see, I would suggest to look in to upgrade part from this link http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/